# How to build the app for ios without giving apple developer account?

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo

I need to build my react-native app for ios. I do not want to publish it to app store. I want it in a form to download it in an ios device , to which I can share the file.

I tried but it showed that a paid developer account was necessary. Is there a way to get the build for free?

Comment: A free developer account can be used to build an ipa that can be installed directly on a device, but there are limitations; you can only install onto a single device and the app will need to be reinstalled after 7 days. Even with a paid account you can only build an image that is installable onto 100 nominated devices. Distribution outside the App Store is not a model that Apple allows